# Mysterious zero

Tags: number-theory

Zero is never supposed to be a 'positive' integer in any mathematical context. Is it true?

According to the definition of an "integer", could it be considered in this way?

And then: if a problem asks for "positive integer solutions" do I have to take into account even zero? I don't think so.

Thank you

Comment: Positive means positive.

Comment: Positive is equivalent to "$>0$".

Comment: What definition of "integer" are you using?

Comment: I think French mathematicians do it differently (when writing in French), but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Some mathematicians use the term 'strictly positive' to denote $x>0$ . So it's possible not all authors agree on the term. Others go through great lengths to not use positive to mean including zero by saying things like 'non-negative'  to mean $x \ge 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)) for many details.

Zero is neither positive nor negative.

One  says "nonnegative integer" to include both the positives and zero.

Similarly, one says "nonpositive integer" to include both the negatives and zero.